# What does もらおうかな mean?

Tags: meaning

Can someone help me understand the meaning of  どれどれ、見せてもらおうかな？
Specifically with the word もらおうかな if it is a verb, a contraction and show me some examples.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> どれどれ、見せてもらおうかな？

The literal translation would be:

> What's going on, let me have a look?

So it's a commanded request, most likely from a parent/teacher/superior/etc. If it was for someone on equal stature, I would use 見せてもらえる？ For someone above me, it would be 見せてもらえませんか？

-- Starfox

Answer (score 2):

This construction is an informal version of 見せてもらおうかな, parsed as

> 見せてもらおう volitional form of the compound verb 見せてもらう
> かな sentence-ending particle indicating uncertainty (or a tentative question)

It means something like "Maybe I should get a look at it (from someone)", depending on the context in which it is used.

Comment: Thank you so so so much.
It is the first time that I ask a question and I did not think they answered me so quickly
So it was just an informal volitional way of the verb 貰う, I spent more than an hour searching the internet for meaning 
I think if they had used the kanji 貰 in the sentence, it would have been easier to understand it
Te mando un saludo desde México y gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: please upvote if you found the answer helpful :)

Comment: @SamaelLara もらう is almost never written with Kanji, sorry to say

Comment: @AeonAkechi 'Almost never' is a little strong, in my opinion. As an auxiliary in the verb-te+morau format, it should be written in hiragana. But as a standalone verb, I've seen in written in kanji now and again.

Comment: "This construction is an informal version of 見せてもらおうかな" Am I missing something, is there another version mentioned somewhere?

Comment: It was different before. He edited it after I answered I think

Comment: Hello Kandyman, I put upbote but it does not mark anything I get this message 
“Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score”.
I guess it's because I'm a newbie, only the popular ones can give votes  笑! 笑! 笑!
And also many thanks to Aeon Akechi and Leebo for their responses.  
!Muchas gracias AMIGOS!